# How do I prevent peanut butter from getting on the handle of the knife?

Tags: cleaning, food

Whenever the peanut butter jar is half-full or less, I end up with peanut butter on the knife handle.  It seems inevitable that the handle will touch the edge of the jar each time you dig deep.  In addition, other jar users often wipe excess off on the edge, making a ring of peanut butter at the top, which often gets on the handle.

How do I stop getting peanut butter on the handle of the knife?

Comment: Hello Minnow and Welcome to Life Hacks Stack Exchange! Have you tried a longer spoon or spatula and rubbing the excess off on the inner sides of the container?

Comment: Just eat it! That's what I do. :-)

Comment: If you eat from the knife handle, the follow up question will be "how do I keep saliva from getting on my knife handle when I lick peanut butter from it".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***This answer may appear obvious, but here is something that might help. Have you tried:***

Using a longer spoon, [knife](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=chef%20knife) or spatula. Also, try storing the container upside down and having others rub the knife against the inside of the container and to avoid rubbing the knife blade on the rim of the jar.

---

**Additional Info**

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/07/24/peanut-butter-knuckles_n_3643920.html

Comment: Obviously not obvious to me!  This is a good solution.  Hopefully the jar~with~a~twist will make it's way to market.  Thanks.